# How to resize a div based on mouse location?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a div that expands left, right, up, and down depending on where the mouse is. But when I move the mouse, the div just pops up and doesn't do anything. What is wrong in what I'm doing?

```
(function() {
    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        draw(e);
    };

    function draw(e) {
        var method = [
            e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.clientX,
            e.pageY ? e.pageY : e.clientY
        ];
        var X = method[0],
            Y = method[1];
        var html = '<div class="box" style="padding-top:' + Y + ';padding-bottom:' + Y + ';padding-left:' + X + ';padding-right:' + X + '"></div>'
            ;
        document.body.innerHTML = html;
    }
})();​
```

Comment: do you have to rewrite the div everytime?

Comment: if Quentin's answer doesn't work then set up an example on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the unit `px`:

```
(function() {
    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        draw(e);
    };

    function draw(e) {
        var method = [
            e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.clientX,
            e.pageY ? e.pageY : e.clientY
        ];
        var X = method[0],
            Y = method[1];
        var html = '<div class="box" style="background-color:red;padding-top:' + Y + 'px;padding-bottom:' + Y + 'px;padding-left:' + X + 'px;padding-right:' + X + 'px"></div>'
            ;
        document.body.innerHTML = html;
    }
})();​
```

(I've also added a red background in order to make the DIV visible)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8LUwp/

Answer (score 1):

`X` and `Y` are numbers. CSS lengths require units. Add some `px`.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing px suffix with the x and Y

```
(function() {
        document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            draw(e);
        };

        function draw(e) {
            var method = [
                e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.clientX,
                e.pageY ? e.pageY : e.clientY
            ];
            var X = method[0],
                Y = method[1];
            var html = '<div class="box" style="padding-top:' + Y +"px" + ';padding-bottom:' + Y +"px" + ';padding-left:' + X +"px" + ';padding-right:' + X  +"px" + '"></div>'
                ;
            document.body.innerHTML = html;
        }
    })();​
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS length attributes (padding, margin, height, width etc.) require units - px, em etc. So just having:

```
padding-top:10
```

is invalid. Instead you need to add units:

```
padding-top:10px
```

So in your case the line setting the html should read:

```
var html = '<div class="box" style="padding-top:' + Y + 'px;padding-bottom:' + Y + 'px;padding-left:' + X + 'px;padding-right:' + X + 'px"></div>';
```